# The content inside double quotes is not printing to System.out

Tags: java

In this program I used `System.out.println`

The content inside the double quotes is not getting printed?

```
public class Demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = new String("suresh");
        String s2 = "suresh";

        System.out.println("s2==s1::"+s2==s1);
    }
}
```

Expected output: `s2==s1::FALSE` 
Actual output: `FALSE`

Answer (score 8):

Because of operator precedence, the `+` operator has higher precedence than the `==` operator.

This expression: `"s2==s1::"+s2==s1` is the same as: `("s2==s1::" + s2) == s1`

In other words, it checks if `"s2==s1::" + s2` is equal to `s1`, and then prints the result of that comparsion (which is `false`).

Try this instead:

```
System.out.println("s2==s1::" + (s2 == s1));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jesper

Answer (score 5):

Doing this

```
System.out.println("s2==s1::"+s2==s1);
```

is the same as doing

```
System.out.println(("s2==s1::"+s2)==s1);
```

because of the precedence of the operators: the `+` operator has higher precedence than the `==` operator.

So you are only getting `true` or `false`

Because you are concatenating the string literal `s2==s1::` with the variable `s2` AND then comparing that reference to variable `s1`

Using parenthesis will resolve the issue

Comment: I assume it was because using parentheses but didn't explain where to like the other answers have.

Answer (score 3):

Put `s2==s1` into parenthesis in order to change the operators' precedence.

```
System.out.println("s2==s1::"+(s2==s1));
```